# Django template ternary for class

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-4, django-templates, ternary-operator

I want to collapse a bootstrap4 accordion based on a conditional.

This code works, but seems silly.

```
{% if missing_data %}
        <div id="collapseExternal" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="externalHeading" data-parent="#accordionExternal">
{% else %}
        <div id="collapseExternal" class="collapse hide" aria-labelledby="externalHeading" data-parent="#accordionExternal">
{% endif %}
```

Based on research I tried

```
<div id="collapseExternal" class="{% if missing_data == True %}collapse show{% else %}collapse hide{% endif %}" aria-labelledby="externalHeading" data-parent="#accordionExternal">
```

As well as

```
<div id="collapseExternal" {% if missing_data %} class="collapse show" {% else %} class="collapse hide" {% endif %} aria-labelledby="externalHeading" data-parent="#accordionExternal">
```

but neither work. They just stay hidden and won't open.

Desired behavior: If the condition is true, have class collapse show, if false, have hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer else where

```
<div id="collapseExternal" class='collapse {{missing_data|yesno:"show,hide"}}' aria-labelledby="externalHeading" data-parent="#accordionExternal">
```

However, I don't know what that really is or is called...